# Undefined service controller using route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I am using angular service with route where my service file is separate. 
and I face branchService is undefined error in console.See code in [Plunker code](https://plnkr.co/edit/YLJoo795kKlC1rEf1QPy) 
Here is branchService.js:

```
 angular.module("myApp").service('branchService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var link = "http://localhost:8008/";
    //----Get Dining Tables`enter code here`
    this.getBranches = function ($scope) {
        return $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: encodeURI(link + "Branch/GetBranches/"),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        }).success(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }).error(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    };
}]);
```

and myController.js is here:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/branches', {
            templateUrl: 'branches.html',
            controller: 'branchController'
        })

        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/branches'
        });
});

app.controller('branchController', ['$scope', '$filter', 'branchService', function ($scope, $filter, branchService) { 
  branchService.getBranches($scope);
}
```

when i run Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error error is show in console

Comment: Check Nilay Kothari's answer. It's probably just that you're not adding the service file to your index.html file, or your naming is off somewhere.

Comment: Check for syntax error message before `Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error`.  App controller needs `}])` at end.

Comment: I already added all js file references in html file, and console not shown any syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before using the service inject it first so you can use it

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute', 'branchService']);
```

EDIT :

This is the problem in branchController.js:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);
```

You injected `ngRoute` again in fact you already added it in app.js  :

`var app = angular.module("myApp",['ngRoute']);`

To fix : remove ng route

```
var app = angular.module("myApp");
```

Comment: create a fiddle and please add the link

Answer (score 1):

Have you add referance of your branchService.js file in index.html or whatever your first page.

Just try to add referance after your myController.js.

Comment: you have problem with your referance files. try to download and referance latest angular and angular route js files.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this. Your service should be loaded first before your controller.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/branches', {
            templateUrl: 'branches.html',
            controller: 'branchController'
        })

        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/branches'
        });
});

app.service('branchService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var link = "http://localhost:8008/";
    //----Get Dining Tables`enter code here`
    this.getBranches = function ($scope) {
        return $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: encodeURI(link + "Branch/GetBranches/"),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        }).success(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }).error(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    };
}]);

app.controller('branchController', ['$scope', '$filter', 'branchService', function ($scope, $filter, branchService) { 
  branchService.getBranches($scope);
}
```

Comment: my service file is separate.